# View's height is 0 under certain conditions when transitioning between Activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

Here is the context: I have a Activity with complex layout to which I want to transition using relatively complex Transitions. The catch is that I need to position one view (`scroll_frame`) below the image (I **can't** use XML), so I need to know it's height. It works fine the first time, however after some number of going back and forth between Activities image's height is suddenly zero (caching, race conditions?)

Here is the snippet of `onCreate`:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    postponeEnterTransition()
    setContentView(R.layout.some_id)

    // ... non-essential stuff.

    Glide.with(this)
            .load([some resource id])
            .into(object : SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(d: Drawable?, t: Transition<in Drawable>?) {
                    // Prepare image.
                    image.setImageDrawable(d)

                    val margin = Math.max(image.measuredHeight, 0)

                    // ... non-essential stuff

                    layoutParams.setMargins(0, margin, 0, 0)

                    // Critical part.
                    scroll_frame?.layoutParams = layoutParams

                    // Start transition.
                    startPostponedEnterTransition()
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that views are not given the measured height in onCreate.

Try this:

```
  //Put this in onCreate
  imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //This is called after view measurements are done.
            //Run your glide code here.
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

that's because your view isn't set yet:

use this:

```
image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            public void onGlobalLayout() {
             //don't forget to remove the listener to prevent being called again by future layout events:
                image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            val margin = Math.max(image.measuredHeight, 0)

                    // ... non-essential stuff

                    layoutParams.setMargins(0, margin, 0, 0)

                    // Critical part.
                    scroll_frame?.layoutParams = layoutParams

                    // Start transition.
                    startPostponedEnterTransition()
          }
}
```